# What is the C equivalent of Perl's file test operators?

Tags: c, file-io, access-control

Perl has a list of file test operators for checking if a file is readable -r, writable -w, or executable -x to the effective user of the process (http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html). How do I do this in C?

```perl
if (-w $file) {
    open FH, "+<", $file or die "$!\n";
}
else {
    open FH, "<", $file or die "$!\n";
}
```

I know libc has a function called access(), but that is for the real user of the process and only useful for setuid programs.

Comment: There's no standard function in C to do this. What you can do is call `fopen(fileName, mode)` and then check if return-value is non-null meaning that `fileName` can be opened in `mode`. Or, use platform-dependent routines...

Comment: With `fopen`, the `mode` won't give you info on execute permission, just read/write.  You'll have to use the OS dependent functions like `stat` for POSIX and whatever the heck MS called `stat` if you need Windows support.

Comment: `access()` is perfectly usable and useful in programs where the real UID is the same as the effective UID.  The key thing is to be aware that it does answer a different question (real UID, real GID) from the normal file access.  However, when the real and effective IDs are the same, it answers a useful question.  Beware auxilliary groups and ACLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't use stat() because attempting to mimic file access is too complicated and will never be portable.

I can't use access() because if I run the program under sudo, I might get back that I can't write a file, when I definitely can.

The only option left is to use open():

```
int fd = open(file, O_RDWR);
if (fd == -1) {
    fd = open(file, O_RDONLY);
}
if (fd == -1) {
    perror("open");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

On POSIX systems, use the `stat` function, and then use the `S_XXX` macros to test the flags, e.g.:

```
struct stat st;
if (stat(file, &st) == 0 && (st.st_mode & S_IWUSR)) {
    // file exists, and is writable by "user"
    ...
}
```

I'm not aware of any "standard" C function to perform the same writability test, other than to actually attempt to open the file and check the resulting error if the file isn't writable.

POSIX does also have `access()` specifically for testing readability and writability, but I mentioned `stat()` first because that's the specific function that Perl's tests attempt to emulate (in most cases).

Comment: There's also POSIX function [`access()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/access.html) which, in a program that is running with EUID = RUID and EGID = RGID, does the requisite test a bit better.  The trouble with using `stat()` is that you need to identify whether the EUID of the process matches the UID of the file, or the EGID of the process matches the GID of the file, or whether one of the auxilliary groups matches the GID of the file, or whether there's an ACL that matches and permits (or denies?) the access, or whether the 'others' access permissions allow access.

Comment: Just seeing if the file is writable by it's owner doesn't mean the process can write it. you would have to check if it's world writable, then group writable and you're in the group, then user writable and that you are that user. but it's even worse than that since there are things like access control lists, and other changes to the way files can be accessed.

Comment: @Jake: the processing sequence is the reverse.  If you own the file, it checks the owner permissions (and that answer is final).  If you don't own the file, it checks group privileges (effective GID and auxilliary groups) and if one of your GIDs matches the file GID, that controls the permissions granted.  Only if you neither own the file nor belong to the group that does own the file do the other permissions matter.  (ACLs add another bag'o'worms to the checking process.)

Comment: The main point is I shouldn't try to mimic file access with stat. I can probably do it with open(), or access() since my program will probably have euid == ruid.